# Correct insert DateTime from c# to mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime-format

I try to insert local time in MongoDB

```
var time = DateTime.Now; // 03.05.2014 18:30:30

var query = new QueryDocument
{
   { "time", nowTime}
};

collection3.Insert(query);
```

But in database I see `ISODate("2014-05-03T15:30:30.170Z")`,
that must be `ISODate("2014-05-03T18:30:30.300Z")`.
Please help me!

Comment: But the time *isn't* 18:30Z. That's in three hours!

Comment: Use `DateTime.UtcNow` and it will match.

Answer (score 15):

I think you're getting confused by time zones. The `Z` at the end of the string indicates that it's in UTC. When you posted this question, it was just after 15:30 UTC.

I strongly suspect that the correct instant in time is being recorded - but it's being recorded as an instant in time without reference to a particular time zone. You can then *convert* that to whatever time zone you want later on, but recording the UTC time is almost always the correct approach.

As an aside, you can make this clearer by using `UtcNow` to start with. That way it's more obvious that you're not trying to obtain a "local" time.

Looking at the MongoDB documentation, it seems that the internal representation is simply a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch - so again, that has no indication of time zone or an offset between UTC and local time. If you want to store a value which can be converted back to the local time you saw when it was recorded (even if you're *now* in a different time zone) you should store a time zone ID and/or the UTC offset as a separate value. That's not needed terribly often, but it's an option.

Answer (score 8):

The MongoDB driver is converting your DateTime to UTC.

If you don't want to bother with time zones, you could change the kind to UTC:

```
time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

I would not recommed this because the database will store a "wrong" Date, but it will show you ISODate("2014-05-03T18:30:30.170Z").

Answer (score 6):

Just define the "Kind" of the DateTime by the "BsonDateTimeOptions" attribute and set it to local:

```
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime SomeDateProperty {get;set;}
```

Comment: Is there a way just to tell it to ignore the field. I asking since telling it Local is also a lie

Answer (score 2):

It could work with:

```
    DateTime t = DateTime.Now;

    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
    .Set("key1", t.ToUniversalTime())
    .CurrentDate("key_updatetime");
```